# Is it a good idea to use 3 sticks of RAM?

Tags: memory, motherboard, desktop-computer, computer-building

I would like to populate only 3 of the 4 RAM slots on my motherboard with 8GB sticks since my forth stick is not working. I am aware that the sticks work in pairs and should be inserted into specific slots as specified in the motherboard manual.

My question is: am I better off using the three working sticks (24GB) and leaving one of them 'unpaired', or should I settle for 16GB?

Comment: Check similar issue here: https://superuser.com/questions/368659/installing-3-ddr2-sticks-which-of-the-4-slots-to-populate. If you want larger capacity but with possible single channel, stay on 3. If you're more care about performance with dual-channel but lesser capacity, use only 2.

Comment: If you're experiencing any sluggishness due to swapping with only rwo modules, then definitely go for more memory (even if it means single-channel performance).  Otherwise, experiment.